# Custom log in JBOSS

Tags: java, jboss, application-server

**Hello, everyone!**
I have a problem with logger. i want to log to a custom files, but theese files are empty.
Could somebody help?

Base logger:

```
import org.apache.log4j.FileAppender;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;

public class BaseLogger {
    private Logger logger;

    private BaseLogger(){

    }

    public BaseLogger(String loggerName) {
        this.logger = Logger.getLogger(loggerName);
        try {
            this.logger.addAppender(createAppender(loggerName + "_APP.LOG"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        logger.info("logger init.");
    }

    public void logInfo(String info){
        logger.info(info);
    }

    public void logInfo(String info, Throwable t){
        logger.info(info, t);
    }

    public void logError(String error) {
        logger.error(error);
    }

    public void logError(String error, Throwable t) {
        logger.error(error, t);
    }

    public void logFatal(String fatal) {
        logger.fatal(fatal);
    }

    public void logFatal(String fatal, Throwable t) {
        logger.fatal(fatal, t);
    }

    private FileAppender createAppender(String fileName) throws IOException {
        return new FileAppender(new PatternLayout(),   System.getProperty("jboss.server.log.dir") + File.separator + fileName);
    }
}
```

Logger class:

```
public class ServicesLogger {
    public static final BaseLogger GENERAL_LOGGER = new BaseLogger("GENERAL_LOGGER");
    public static final BaseLogger SERVICE_EXECUTOR = new  BaseLogger("SERVICE_EXECUTOR");
}
```

when i invoke ServicesLogger.SERVICE_EXECUTOR.logInfo("info"); in jboss console is appear this text, but in file not.
what is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add to your code only this:

```
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
...
public class SomeClass {
    private Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("GENERAL_LOGGER");
...
    logger.info("some info");
}
```

And then add appender to server configuration file:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
...
    <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="GENERAL_LOGGER_handler">
        <formatter>
            <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
        </formatter>
        <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="GENERAL_LOGGER_APP.LOG"/>
        <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
        <append value="true"/>
    </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
    <logger category="GENERAL_LOGGER">
        <level name="DEBUG"/>
        <handlers>
            <handler name="GENERAL_LOGGER_handler"/>
        </handlers>
    </logger>
...
```

Comment: could you tell me how it may be works in weblogic app server?